# unrecognized selector sent to instance - can someone Help me?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone

Well I'm trying to set the label text with a Json response if u look at the code if I use @`tituloReceita` to put it on label it works but i have to use @`ingredientes` if u take a look here http://blessing.com.br/aplicativos/receitasJson.php, it possible to see that the @`ingredientes` its a little bigger than @`tituloReceita`.

code:

```
NSData *data=[NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://blessing.com.br/aplicativos/receitasJson.php"]];
    NSError *error=nil;
    NSDictionary *dict = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:0 error:&error];
    NSArray *json = dict[@"receitas"];


for (NSDictionary *dic in json) {
    if ([dic[@"tituloReceita"] isEqualToString:titulo]) {

        self.label1 = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(25, 50, 150, 20)];
        //set the label text
        self.label1.numberOfLines = 10;
        self.label1.text = [dic objectForKey:@"ingredientes"];
        //set the lable font
        self.label1.font = [UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:10.0f];
        //se the text alignment
        self.label1.textAlignment =  NSTextAlignmentCenter;
        [sView addSubview:self.label1];


     }

}
```

after this, the app crash and log this:

> *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[__NSCFArray length]:
>   unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x10c01ad90'

But if I use the other that a said the @`tituloReceita` it works perfectly, this app is like a recipe book.

Comment: Please check your JSON carefully. `tituloReceita` is a string and `ingredientes` is an array.

Comment: `[dic objectForKey:@"ingredientes"];` its an array not a string

Comment: @SushilSharma sorry by my mistake Im new on iOS and objective-c

Comment: `[__NSCFArray length]:unrecognized selector` That means somewhere you called (potentially not directly you, but an "hidden" call) `length` methdo on a `NSArray` object (you mismatch the real class of the object and thought it could call `length`, but that's not the case since it's a `NSArray` object). With practice, we can say that somewhere you mismatch a `NSArray` object with a `NSString` object. Pinpointing the exact line should give you `self.label1.text = [dic objectForKey:@"ingredientes"];`. So `[dic objectForKey:@"ingredientes"];` is a `NSArray`, not a `NSString`, your parsing is wrong.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to the JSON, the value of key `ingredientes` is an Array, you cannot use it as String:

[image]

If you want to use all ingredientes, try:

```
NSArray *ingredientes = [dic objectForKey:@"ingredientes"];
if (ingredientes != nil) {
    self.label1.text = [ingredientes componentsJoinedByString:@","];
}
```

If you want to use first ingredient, try:

```
NSArray *ingredientes = [dic objectForKey:@"ingredientes"];
if (ingredientes != nil && ingredientes.count > 0) {
    self.label1.text = [ingredientes firstObject];
}
```

The last problem is: you create labels with same frame in a loop, that makes all labels together. Maybe you should change frame for each label to place them at good positions.

Comment: so, how can I use to put it on a uilabel?

Comment: @YunCHEN good answer, u know how can I  change the "," for break lines to make it clear and easier?

Comment: @MatheusRohwedder, try @"\n". And remember to set label's numberOfLines property to 0.

Answer (score 0):

From json at http://blessing.com.br/aplicativos/receitasJson.php. "ingredientes" key contains an array and you are assigning it to text take takes string value only. So join object of array and make string. Like for e.g. `[[dic objectForKey:@"ingredientes"] componentsJoinedByString:@","];`

Comment: good answer, but u know how can I change the "," for break lines to make the app clear ?

Comment: yes instead of , use \n for break line. But you need to make label.numberOfLines = 0 so it become multi line.

Comment: the Json code i can't change so how can I substitute it programmatically?

Comment: replace  [[dic objectForKey:@"ingredientes"] componentsJoinedByString:@","]; with  [[dic objectForKey:@"ingredientes"] componentsJoinedByString:@"\n"];

Comment: Sorry, I understand wrong, Im thinking that u said to change on Json, thank u so much.